# Showing and Hiding forms all over the project

Tags: c#, oop

I want to hide and close a form from every form of the project. I mean, if I am in form2, at clicking a button, I want form1 to be shown or hidden, depends of necesities. I can't find a way, I searched everywhere I could about OOP of doing this, but I still can't figure it out. Do I have to create a new instance of every form everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, The reshowing i don't know 100% sure, but hiding them should be easy with the following code:

```
    YourFormName newYourFormName = new YourFormName();
    newYourFormName.Parent = this;
    newYourFormName.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide(); // or to close it:
    this.Close();
```

Add this to the button, replace YourFormName for your form that you want to close.

For re-show you could try an if statement, im not at my PC atm so cant check for working code on that. but this should work.